# Is there any real protection against Google on Android phones?

Tags: android, google, tracking

There's a lot one can do to protect his self identity and from being tracked on standard computer machine, but I wonder if there's any way to do so(or at least as close as it possible) on the Android phones?

For example, how can one make sure Google won't get access to his contact list? I'm not talking about setting the things up as you wish at the Google's account page, I'm talking about ensuring Google won't be able to have access to it.

They probably store some hardware info of the cellphone as well and so on - is there any way to actually protect your self from this and yet benefit from today's new smartphones that are available and running Android?

Comment: Is turning off data connectivity appropriate?  Faraday cage?  Connected to wi-fi with no Internet connectivity?

Answer (score 1):

One could build a custom AOSP based ROM with no google services, API's.
I have come across ROM's that do this, cannot guarantee on the completeness since I did not test it myself .